# web3.eth.accounts returning a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm following a [tutorial here that uses testrpc with web3.js](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/full-stack-hello-world-voting-ethereum-dapp-tutorial-part-1-40d2d0d807c2). After installing the packages ethereumjs-testrpc and web3js, testrpc is started which gives 10 available accounts and their private keys.

web3 is at 1.0.0-beta.18 and ethereumjs-testrpc at 4.1.1.

When the following code is run

```
Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
web3.eth.accounts
```

I get the following output instead of the 10 accounts as shown in the tutorial. What went wrong?

```
Accounts {
  currentProvider: [Getter/Setter],
  _requestManager:
   RequestManager {
     provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
     providers:
      { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
        HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
        IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
     subscriptions: {} },
  givenProvider: null,
  providers:
   { WebsocketProvider: [Function: WebsocketProvider],
     HttpProvider: [Function: HttpProvider],
     IpcProvider: [Function: IpcProvider] },
  _provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
  setProvider: [Function],
  _ethereumCall:
   { getId:
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'net_version' },
     getGasPrice:
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_gasPrice' },
     getTransactionCount:
      { [Function: send]
        method: [Object],
        request: [Function: bound ],
        call: 'eth_getTransactionCount' } },
  wallet:
   Wallet {
     length: 0,
     _accounts: [Circular],
     defaultKeyName: 'web3js_wallet' } }
```

Later in the tutorial, `web3.eth.accounts` is needed when deploying the contract

```
deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],
    {data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
```

Answer (score 7):

That tutorial was written before web3.js v1 came out. The API has changed significantly in v1, including `eth.accounts`. You can either pin to an older version of web3.js, like `0.19.0`, or find the equivalent method in the new [v1 docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/).

Retrieving the accounts is now done asynchronously, like many other calls in the new API. So you can call it with a callback or using promises. Printing the list of accounts to your console would look like:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(console.log);
// or
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(console.log);
```

From the [`web3.eth.getAccounts` v1 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getaccounts)

So specifically rewriting the section you referenced at the end:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(function (accounts) {
  return VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],
    {data: byteCode, from: accounts[0], gas: 4700000});
})
.then(function (deployedContract) {
  // whatever you want to do with deployedContract...
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I am also having a hard time finding how to update this code `deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Rama','Nick','Jose'],
    {data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})` now that `web3.eth.getAccounts()` uses Promises.

Comment: Ok, added a section to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If `web3.eth.accounts` is not showing the expected result
then, follow this two simple step (Inside the truffle console)

1. `web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(acc){ accounts = acc })`
2. `accounts`

That's is...
if you want specific account then `accounts[0/1/2...9]`